# Is there a way to access the WiFi connection through the shell?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, networking

Is there any way of seeing/manipulating connection represented by the WiFi symbol on the desktop?

For example, programmatically connecting and disconnecting to a router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using `nmcli` command.

For example, you can turn Wi-Fi off by running

```
nmcli nm wifi off
```

You can turn it on by

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```

Other options of this command can be seen by running

```
man nmcli
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need more advanced options, you can use directly via intefaces. There is great tutorial on Debian Wiki (https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Command_Line). Warning: There is a bug, network-manager in gnome-shell (i don't know if it happens in Unity) does not recognize any interface set directly via /etc/interfaces.

Comment: It is not a bug, but a feature not to manage interfaces, that are set up manually.